# In Keras, If samples_per_epoch is less than the 'end' of the generator when it (loops back on itself) will this negatively affect result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, theano, keras

I'm using Keras with Theano to train a basic logistic regression model.

Say I've got a training set of 1 million entries, it's too large for my system to use the standard `model.fit()` without blowing away memory.

- I decide to use a python generator function and fit my model using `model.fit_generator()`.
- My generator function returns batch sized chunks of the 1M training examples (they come from a DB table, so I only pull enough records at a time to satisfy each batch request, keeping memory usage in check).
- It's an endlessly looping generator, once it reaches the end of the 1 million, it loops and continues over the set

There is a mandatory argument in `fit_generator()` to specify `samples_per_epoch`.  The documentation indicates

> **samples_per_epoch:** integer, number of samples to process before going to the next epoch.

I'm assuming the `fit_generator()` doesn't reset the generator each time an epoch runs, hence the need for a infinitely running generator.

I typically set the `samples_per_epoch` to be the size of the training set the generator is looping over.

However, if `samples_per_epoch` this is smaller than the size of the training set the generator is working from and the `nb_epoch` > 1:

- Will you get odd/adverse/unexpected training resulting as it seems the epochs will have differing sets training examples to fit to?
- If so, do you 'fastforward' you generator somehow?

Answer (score 3):

I'm dealing some something similar right now. I want to make my epochs shorter so I can record more information about the loss or adjust my learning rate more often.

Without diving into the code, I think the fact that `.fit_generator` works with the randomly augmented/shuffled data produced by the keras builtin `ImageDataGenerator` supports your suspicion that it doesn't reset the generator per epoch. So I believe you should be fine, as long as the model is exposed to your whole training set it shouldn't matter if some of it is trained in a separate epoch.

If you're still worried you could try writing a generator that randomly samples your training set.

Comment: As you note, it's seems it does not reset or do anything other than call the generator.  The one assertion I'd want to look deeper at is if there is any pros/cons to this statement:  "As long as the model is exposed to your whole training set it shouldn't matter if some of it is trained in a separate epoch."  In my mind, changing the training set means between epochs (using in something like GDC) means you're changing parameters of what you're trying to decend, so you can't judge weather a later epoch is improving or not on the prior.